# Можно ли логировать ip адреса в iptables?

Tags: iptables, ddos

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j DROP
```

К примеру вместо `DROP` вставить `LOG` что он будет логировать и куда? И можно ли как то логировать `ip` адреса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте про действие ULOG, оно вам в userspace логи высовывать будет, а дальше хоть в mysql. А так действие LOG в системный журнал пишет.

Comment: а будет ли оно писать мне ip? и где же разыскать системный журнал?

Comment: /var/log/messages скорее всего...

Answer (score 2):

В системный журнал будет писать

`LOG level warning prefix`IPTABLES DROP '`если добавть prefix, то будет писать с префиксом, который можно спокойно syslog-ng обработать и вывести в отдельный лог

Comment: пример    Jan 21 04:08:39 hostname  kernel: IPTABLES DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=87.x.x.x.x DST=87.y.y.y.y LEN=158 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=138